# How to destroy the jQuery UI combobox functionality and get the original behaviour

Tags: jquery

I'm using [this jquery-ui-combobox](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood)  in my application. And there is no way specified to destroy the combo box functionality. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using a part of a comment in that article. It's to add a customized destroy functionality, and it works fine.

```
    destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.button.remove();
        this.element.show();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
    }
```

Then call it by,

```
element.combobox('destroy');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a custom implementation of jQuery UI Autocomplete, you could call the `destroy()` method, something like this:

```
if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
    input.autocomplete("destroy"); 
}
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-destroy

Comment: You should using something like this: if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
        input.autocomplete("destroy"); }

Comment: hi thanks for your support, with your answer I got a clue to use a correct approach. The way I did is posted as an answer.